# Is formatting recovery partition to update OS recovery safe

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, data-recovery, windows-10-upgrade

So, I bought my HP Notebook 15 2 years back with Windows 8.1 installed. It came with a factory reset recovery partition. Last year, in the July of 2015, I updated to Windows 10, free of charge, as my software and hardware were compatible. But, long story short, I had to use this recovery partition, and it, as I expected, restored back to Windows 8.1. So I had to go through the upgrade process again. So, more to the point, I would like to know if it would be possible to format my current recover partition, and use it as a USB flash drive, and create a recover drive on that, and how.

Comment: Sorry, but it is hard to make sense of your question. *Format partition and use it as a USB flash drive*?

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity. I say this because, on the "Create a Recovery Drive" GUI, it displays "insert a USB flash drive." I'm wondering if this partition will be compatible.

Comment: Ok, so you want to replace your current Windows 8.1 partition with Windows 10 recovery partition. However when you try to do it, system does not allow you to select the existing partition and instead asks to insert a USB flash drive. Right?

Comment: Yes. But note I have not formatted it yet. But I know it's capable of formatting drives, as it also says in the GUI "The drive must hold at least 25 GB and *everything on it will be deleted*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to format/delete an **OEM recovery partition** (which holds recovery tools from, say Lenovo or Dell) as long as you don't want any of it's offering.

But it is not recommended to delete/modify **Windows recovery partition** (and other reserved partitions), which are created during a fresh install of Windows onto a blank drive.

Also, whatever you do it's really **unlikely** you can have a HDD partition show up as removable USB drive. Even if you achieve so with sophisticated methods it's unlikely you can boot from it and install Windows without having drawbacks.

I would suggest creating a bootable USB with tools like *Rufus* or simply burn the DVD for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely format the recovery partition once upgraded to Windows 10. You can do this from

> Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Disk Manager

Then you can use it as a separate disk for storing files and not be troubled with going back to 8.1.

But if C: drive and that partition are actually on one single drive then  Windows won't allow you to create recovery partition.

Consider if your disk crashes. You would lose both recovery and the main C: drive. What's the point in creating recovery? It's like making backups of a project in the same file, so if the file gets destroyed, so are the backups destroyed as well.

If you have blank rewritable CDs or DVDs then you can create recovery boot disk there if you have no empty pendrives to spare.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not take offense, I do not mean it. The question was "is it safe" and safety is relative.

Given your level of experience and confidence a safe way would be to leave partition as is, buy a USB drive, "play" with it (create recovery disk, restore from it). When you have tested the restore process, only then you can delete current partition and try to replace it with Windows 10.

If you started with deleting current recovery partition and something goes wrong, then you are left with no other option but getting physical installation media. Hence it is not safe in your particular case.

Comment: Are you implying that I am inexperienced and not confident?

Comment: How many times did you perform Windows 10 recovery from a system recovery partition?